# Meaning of "same day as one another"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I want to know the meaning of the phrase "on the same day as one another".

The complete sentence where the phrase appears is

> The orchids and roses were delivered on the same day as one another.

Comment: Your title and your text use different phrasing, one of which is idiomatic (the title, using "one another") and one of which is not (the text).  Assuming you meant the phrasing in the title, it simply means they were both delivered on the same day; the orchids were delivered on the same day as the roses, and the roses were delivered on the same day as the orchids.

Comment: I (and another editor) altered the question to make it consistent in the question head and the question body. If the resulting wording is not what you had in mind, sudhira mokshagundam, please clarify what your intended question was.

Comment: @SvenYargs OP's clarification first, then comes edit.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please provide broader context (whole paragraph/ even more). The sentence fails to make sense in isolation. Good Luck.

Comment: The sentence seems clear enough...both the roses and orchids were delivered on the same day.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to ask why is "as one another" even used. Consider:

> The orchids and roses were delivered on the same day.

This would usually be correctly understood that they were both delivered on the same day, but one could also ask, same day as what? "Same" means two or more things that occurred concurrently, that may mean the orchids and roses, or "the orchids and roses" (as one entity) and "something else". Also consider:

> The orchids and roses were delivered on the same day as the milk was dropped off.

Here the orchids, roses and milk all arrived on the same day. But we could go further:

> The orchids and roses were delivered on the same day as the milk was dropped off and the furniture arrived, respectively.

Here the orchids were delivered on the same day as the milk, and the roses were delivered on the same day as the furniture.

So, you may ask again, why is "as one another" even used? Because it **removes ambiguity** that the multiple entities relating to the "same" are just the orchids and roses, not "the orchids and roses" and "something else". You can probably also say:

> The orchids and roses were delivered on the same day as each other.